# Supersingular elliptic curves with extra automorphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $p$ be a prime greater than 3, and let $M$ be a positive integer prime to $p$. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of isomorphism classes of pairs $(E, C_M)$, where $E$ is a supersingular elliptic curve over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ and $C_M$ a cyclic subgroup of $E$ of order $M$. Then, by Deligne-Rapoport, $X_0(pM)_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}$ has two components isomorphic to $X_0(M)_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}$, and they meet transversally at "the points'' in $\Sigma$.

Let $\Sigma_4$ (resp. $\Sigma_6$) be the subset of $\Sigma$ which consists of pairs $(E, C_M)$ such that $\# \text{Aut} (E, C_M)=4$ (resp. $6$). If $M=1$ then an element in $\Sigma_4$ or in $\Sigma_6$, if it exists, is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

My question is as follows: Suppose that $M>1$. Let $s=(E, C_M) \in \Sigma_6$ (or in $\Sigma_4$). I guess $s$ is not defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (but only in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$), but I cannot prove this. I hope someone in MO knows the answer.

Comment: More precisely, I am asking that $\varphi(s)=(E^{(p)}, C_M^{(p)})$ is isomorphic to $s=(E, C_M)$ or not when $s \in \Sigma_6$ (or in $\Sigma_4$), where $\varphi$ is the Frobenius endomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a supersingular elliptic curve $E / {\bf F}_p$ with
an automorphism of order $4$ or $6$, then the automorphism is not
defined over ${\bf F}_p$, but plenty of cyclic subgroups *are*
defined over ${\bf F}_p$.  This is because the Frobenius endomorphism $\varphi$
generates an imaginary quadratic ring and there are many choices of
$a, b \in \bf Z$ with $a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ for which the endomorphism
$\alpha = a + b\varphi$ has cyclic kernel.  (The condition on $a$ assures that 
$\alpha$ is separable.)

Comment: @Elkies; For $s=(E, C_M) \in \Sigma_6$, is it true that $\varphi(s)$ is not isomorphic to $s$?

Comment: In general it depends on your choice of $C_M$.  In the case I described,
where $C_M = \ker(\alpha)$ with $\alpha = a + b \varphi$,
it *is* ismorphic, because $\alpha$ commutes with $\varphi$;
thus it is a counterexample to your conjecture.

Comment: Here are simpler explicit examples when the same $p,M$ allow 
either $\varphi(s)=s$ or $\varphi(s)\neq s$.
suppose $p \equiv 5 \bmod 6$, choose $E: y^2 = x^3 - 1$,
and let $M=2$.  Then if $C_M = \{ {\bf 0}, (1,0) \}$
then $C_M = \varphi C_M$, but the other two choices
(which are $\{ {\bf 0}, (\rho,0) \}$ with $\rho^2+\rho+1=0$)
are conjugate under $\varphi$.

Comment: @Elkies; In the example you gave, $\#\Sigma_6=0$ (ref. Edixhoven, L’action de l’algèbre de Hecke sur les groupes de composantes des jacobiennes des courbes modulaires est “Eisenstein” in Asterique, p.168). So, the above pairs do not have the group of automorphisms of order 6.

Comment: @Elkies; If $\#\text{Aut}(E, C_M)=6$, then the order of the automorphism group of $C_M$ is also divisible by 6. Therefore all prime divisors of $M$ must be congruent to 1 modulo 3.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that only $E$ was required to have extra automorphisms, not the pair $(E,C_M)$.  Let me think about this further; my answer might be answering a different question.

Comment: Suppose $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$. Let $M \equiv 1 \mod 3$ be a prime. Then, the number of cyclic subgroups of order $M$ is $M+1$. Let $E : y^2=x^3 -1$, and let $\rho$ be a 3rd root of unity. Then, there are only two isomorphism classes of pairs $(E, C_M)$ whose automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}/6$. Let $C$, $D$ be two such cyclic groups. Then, $\rho(C)=C$ and $\rho(D)=D$. If $C' \neq C, D$, then $\rho(C')\neq C'$ and $(E, C'), (E, \rho(C')), (E, \rho^2(C'))$ belong to the same isomorphism class. Thus, my question in this case is whether $\varphi(C)=D$ or not?